# jQuery fade-in images after delayed loading

Tags: jquery, image, loading, fadein, delay

i'm using this to delay the loading of my images:

HTML:

```
<img src="loading.gif" delayedSrc="url/to/real/image.png" />
```

jquery:

```
image.attr('src', currentImage.attr('delayedSrc'));
```

now when the loading has finished, instead of just switching from the loading.gif to the real image if want it to fade in.
I tried:

```
image.attr('src', currentImage.attr('delayedSrc')).load(function() {
    image.hide().fadeIn(1000);
}
```

This works fine if the images have not yet been cached (loading iamge shows, then real image fades in). the problem is, though, that if the images have already been cached, they are shown when the page loads (no loading image is shown), then are being hidden and faded in again which looks pretty ugly..

how can i solve this? my thought was maybe to check if the images have been cached and only do the fadein if they haven't... after all the fading is just necessary to get a softer transition between the loading image and the real image. but how would i check this? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fade from one image to another using only a single image.  You can fade a single image from zero opacity to full opacity if that effect is an OK visual.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/38Afs/

HTML:

```
<img class="delayImg" delayedSrc="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344291068_HdnTo-L.jpg" />​
```

CSS:

```
.delayImg {opacity:0;}​
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".delayImg").each(function() {
        this.onload = function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);
        };
        this.src = this.getAttribute("delayedSrc");
    });
});​
```

Note: `onload` will not fire reliably in all browsers when you change `.src`, only when it is first set so it is a problem to have an initial image `.src` set and then change it later and get notified when the new one is loaded.  If you really wanted that effect, then you would probably need to either use the background-image for the first image or use two image objects on top of one another where you fade out the first one and fade in the second one.

Here's an example of creating a second image so you can fade one out and the other in where it fades as soon as it loads: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yvc8d/.

And here's one where it fades later upon a user action: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/LRRRm/.

Comment: using a background image along with opacity did the trick, thanks!